# 'wp-config.php' already exists error in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I install wordpress in the subfolder on my server. In the root of the server the joomla websit is already install. After succesfull installation when I am trying to go to home page then it redirect me to the installation page and show me this message

> The file 'wp-config.php' already exists. If you need to reset any of
>   the configuration items in this file, please delete it first.

Thanks

Comment: Check the following link from official WordPress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Answer (score 1):

Its a browser cache issue. 
If you are using chrome then go to

> settings -> show advanced settings -> clear browsing data

Hope this simple trick works for you.